# Checking url string in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Admit that I suck in writing regular expression. Please help me to solve how to write regular expression for `success-apply` founded in URL just like `http://www.example.com/success-apply/`

Comment: Why would you need a regex for that?

Comment: @DavidBrabant need to set a goal in google analystics.

Comment: I mean, why can't you use a string replace instead?

Comment: @DavidBrabant just find whether `success-apply` is included in URL string or not.

Comment: url.Contains("success-apply") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
(success-apply)
```

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect... because you are not finding the match sucess-apply in an url... you re finding in the entire text, whatever it is

Comment: You mean I'm not checking if it's a valid url before I'm searching for the keyword? I don't think this is what the OP is asking for. He has a list of urls (I assume), wether they are valid or not is in this case not the question, but if these strings contain the keywords or not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the pattern `success-apply` changes:

```
example\.com\/([^\/]+)
# capture everything that is not a forward slash one or unlimited times
```

Here is [this regex example](https://regex101.com/r/eH7nT6/1) with PCRE (PHP).

If you however only want to know if the string is *there at all*, regular expressions seem a bit of an overkill. Consider the following PHP code:

```
if (strpos($url, 'success-apply') !== FALSE) {
   // do sth useful
}
```